# using where sentences into a join linq

Tags: linq

I want to retrieve just Rolepermissions where the user name is Bob but not return results, i used this code:

```
var rolePermissions = from r in roles
                          join ur in userInRoles on r.RoleId equals ur.RoleId
                          join u in userModule.Where(x => x.UserName=="Bob" ) on ur.UserId equals u.UserId
                          join rp in rolePermission on r.RoleId equals rp.RoleId
select (new RolePermissions { RoleName= r.RoleName, Priority= rp.Priority, Modules= rp.Modules});
```

I have data in my database when i used the code

```
var rolePermissions = from r in roles
                          join ur in userInRoles on r.RoleId equals ur.RoleId
                          join u in userModule on ur.UserId equals u.UserId
                          join rp in rolePermission on r.RoleId equals rp.RoleId
select (new RolePermissions { RoleName= r.RoleName, Priority= rp.Priority, Modules= rp.Modules});
```

It's return the permissions for all user but if i add the where clause return any.

Comment: Please read your question to yourself. It doesn't make sense, something is missing.

Comment: I added an answer below of where I would put the where clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var rolePermissions = from r in roles
                      join ur in userInRoles on r.RoleId equals ur.RoleId
                      join u in userModule on ur.UserId equals u.UserId
                      join rp in rolePermission on r.RoleId equals rp.RoleId
                      where u.username = "Bob"
select (new RolePermissions { RoleName= r.RoleName, Priority= rp.Priority, Modules= rp.Modules});
```

Update the where clause to use whatever table username is stored in.  Or make it a variable that gets passed in and make the where statement use the variable.